# AE Controller for changing layer into specific colours

Tags: video, after-effects, animation, adobe, after-effects-expressions

I'm trying to create an **Essential Graphic** that allows the user to change a layer's colour into *4 specific ones*:

*Teal: 7, 250, 198

Pink: 252, 12, 119

Black: 0, 0, 0

White: 255, 255, 255*

- *Colour Control* isn't an option as it gives too much freedom.
- *Checkbox Control* isn't either as it is not a 2 colours boolean/switch.

A Slider Control I think would be a good option but I need something similar to the *clamp expression* to keep the slider in control, something that would make my slider move in ones or specific steps.

Maybe I'm completely off track, I'm open to better solutions!

Answer (score 1):

Use a dropdown. Select **Dropdown Expression Control** from **Effects>Expression Controls** and hit edit to input the colour names.

[image]

Then use a `switch` to deal with the four possible choices.

```
let colourChoice = Math.round(thisComp.layer("White Solid 1").effect("Dropdown Menu Control")("Menu"));
switch (colourChoice){
    case 1 : [7, 250, 198, 255]/255.0;
        break;
    case 2 : [252, 12, 119, 255]/255.0;
        break;
    case 3 : [0, 0, 0, 0];
        break;
    default:  [1, 1, 1, 1];
```

}

**N.B.:**

- `Math.round` on the firstline is to convert the numeric result returned from the dropdown to an integer, I'm not sure what kind of numerical value is returned from a dropdown, but just using `let colourChoice = thisComp.layer("White Solid 1").effect("Dropdown Menu Control")("Menu")` doesn't work.
- Colours in expressions are four-dimensional RGBA arrays, because even if they don't use alpha they need a value for alpha.
- And finally the `/ 255` after the array is to convert the 0-255 RGBA values into 0-1.0 floating point values for colour. You could do the maths beforehand, but it's more legible like this.

Comment: I've been using AE 2019 but I see now the great advantage of 2020.
I've tried it but whatever I do it keeps saying `Error: Expected: ;`

Comment: 2019 uses a different expression language. Instead of `switch` you'll have to use `if(colourChoice === 1){…} else if (colourChoice === 2){…` And use `var` instead of `let`

Comment: 2019 doesn't support Dropdown Menu, so I've tried on 2020 but that's where it shows that `;` problem.